# Best way to convert a Java string to Solr criteria query

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr, solrj, criteriaquery

I am not well versed in java and Solr, so apologies if this is a basic question.

I have a string that I need to convert to a Solr criteria.

```java
String rule = "(index_key_parentcategory = \"Workwear\" AND index_key_category = \"Women\" AND index_key_subcategory = \"ShortSleeve\") AND (locale IN \"en_US \")"
```

I want to convert the above string to Solr `Criteria` using criteria in Query: `org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.Criteria`

Could you help me with that, please?